# How to make dovecot not ask passwords from localhost?

Tags: pam, dovecot

I have set up dovecot server and I'm currently using offline imap to sync my gmail to the dovecot imap running on the localhost.

Currently I'm using plain text authentication, but this results in every single mail client to ask & remember my user name password just to access mail from localhost.

Is there a way to set up dovecot such that it will not ask me for authentication when I'm trying to log in to it from gnus from localhost for example? Or make it ask pam/gnomekeyring/anything to not ask me?

ps. there are no plans to allow accessing dovecot server not from localhost. Not even from local network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options come to my mind:

- First, if you are on the same
  machine, you could just use the
  underlying mail store directly,
  without going thru IMAP. Depending on
  the store and client used, this may
  result in some troubles reflecting
  changes back to IMAP, though.
- Second, use Dovecot's mechanism for
  [pre-authenticated
  sessions](http://wiki1.dovecot.org/PreAuth),
  together with an `inetd` or
  [ucspi-tcp's
  `tcpserver`](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html)
  if you need to listen on a TCP port
  for you client of choice.
- Finally, you could setup Kerberos
  ticket authentication and use that
  with Dovecot via GSSAPI. But that's
  probably overkill for your scenario.

Comment: On `mutt` (and possibly other MUAs), preauth'd sessions can be used by setting `tunnel` or similar variable to `"dovecot --exec-mail imap"`.

Comment: I'm using `gnus` and it works wonderful `(setq gnus-select-method '(nnimap "localmail" (nnimap-stream shell)))           
(setq imap-shell-program "/usr/sbin/dovecot --exec-mail imap")`

Answer (score 2):

The [comment from @grawity](https://serverfault.com/questions/165862/how-to-make-dovecot-not-ask-passwords-from-localhost#comment143190_165895) on the other answer, although now outdated, led me to the solution I needed. It deserves an answer of its own. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/530586/295645) to a [closely related question](https://serverfault.com/q/530585/295645) provided the missing link.

Pre-authenticated sessions can be obtained by piping through a Dovecot command.
Recent (>= 2.0) versions of Dovecot provide the `imap` command, which on Debian and Ubuntu is located at `/usr/lib/dovecot/imap`.
On older versions you'd instead run `dovecot --exec-mail imap` (located in `/usr/sbin`).

For my `mutt`, the required [.muttrc setting](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#tunnel) would thus be

```
tunnel=/usr/lib/dovecot/imap
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (2.2.32+) Dovecot allows you to create a passdb definiteion, that has the options `allow_real_nets=127.0.0.1/32` and `nopassword` in the `override_fields` setting.  This will allow any password, but only from the specified subnet (IE localhost).  You can still use your normal passdb definition to ensure the mailbox correctly exists, but use override_fields or similar to set these two options to restrict it.