# IMAP preauth with Dovecot

Tags: dovecot, imap

What's the command line for preauth IMAP using Dovecot? Many sites give:

```
dovecot --exec-mail imap
```

But on my system this returns:

```
Usage: dovecot [-F] [-c <config file>] [-p] [-n] [-a] [--help] [--version]
       [--build-options] [reload] [stop]
Fatal: Unknown argument: --exec-mail
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make dovecot not ask passwords from localhost?](https://serverfault.com/questions/165862/how-to-make-dovecot-not-ask-passwords-from-localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dovecot --exec-mail imap
```

is not a valid command line switch in recent releases of Dovecot. There is now a separate binary named simply "imap" which launches a pre-authenticated IMAP session.

Source of information: [Dovecot's upgrading to 2.0 instructions](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Upgrading/2.0)

On Ubuntu, this binary is not in the default path, it's located at /usr/lib/dovecot/imap